# How to smooth velocity in the edges of a path

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to take off and land a helicopter and I wanted to know if there is a function that could smooth only the beggining and end of the path and keep a constant velocity in the middle ?

Comment: Do you just need a value between 0 and 1 saying what % of maximum speed you should use in the current frame? What kind of information is available to the function? It's hard to tell exactly what kind of answer would actually be helpful to you without more details in the question. If you were to edit your question to include the code you already have, that would clear up a lot of things.

Comment: I think you should look for ease in/out lerp. Maybe this could help https://forum.unity.com/threads/a-smooth-ease-in-out-version-of-lerp.28312/ Maybe ease in/out quad...